# Musk bought Twitter with $13b loans - why is *Twitter* liable for this debt rather than Musk?

Tags: loans, debt, corporate-acquisition

Elon Musk bought Twitter in late 2022 for $44 billion.  My understanding is that $13b of the total price was financed by bank loans.

So, why is Twitter *itself* on the hook for the loan repayments?

If I buy an asset by taking on debt, I'm liable for the debt myself, not the asset!  How can someone buy a business, yet the business is somehow responsible for repaying a portion of its own purchase price?

Comment: Can you reference where it is said that Twitter is liable for the debts?

Comment: How does this relate to personal finance?

Answer (score 7):

The way the deal was structured was that Twitter essentially repurchased its own shares from the public and then sold itself to Musk.

Twitter spent $13b on that, Musk spent IIRC another ~$26B, and his partners filled in the rest.

Comment: I think the point is that the debt held by Musk is not, technically, Twitter's "legal responsibility", so this is about the amounts he borrowed for his own $26B contribution to the pot.

Comment: No, the 13b **is** Twitter's responsibility. The 26b Musk paid out of his own pocket is separate and is based on him selling and leveraging his Tesla shares.

Comment: I see you're right - wasn't aware of that portion of the arrangement. Revising my answer based on this.

Answer (score 1):

Simple terms - assume you run a small incorporated restaurant. Assume this corporation owns its building. That restaurant could get a bank loan to fund its operations, and pledge the land and building as collateral.

Now assume your neighbor is currently the shareholder of this business [assume it doesn't yet have any bank debt]. You want to buy it, but have no cash. You ask the bank for a loan. There are two ways to do this: you could borrow the money personally, or you could ask that the bank give the money to the corporation once you own it. The purchase agreement would be something like a 4-way deal between you, the bank, your neighbor, and the corporation.

The corporation takes on debt from the bank, pledging its assets as collateral. It uses this new cash to pay your neighbor for their shares. Assume for simplicity that the value of the corporation is now minimal, with new debt roughly equal to its asset value.

You now give your neighbor some agreed 'additional value' for the shares they still hold. Since the corporation has taken on new debt, those shares aren't worth what they were worth before, and whatever amount you are paying you can now afford.

At the end of the day, you own a restaurant, which has assets and debt, and the debt is owed to the bank, just like in the first example above.

For the twitter deal, this describes the $13B of debt owed by Twitter, and the additional amounts contributed by Musk and the other shareholders represents the 'additional value' also described above. Note that Musk will also expect Twitter to 'pay for' the debt he took on personally, because he won't want to pay interest costs on an asset that loses him money.

Comment: @littleadv I've edited to reflect that Twitter also had its own debt from this.

Answer (score -1):

What Musk could have done: Buy Twitter for 44bn, no he owns Twitter, Twitter asks the banks for a 13bn loan and gets it, and pays 13bn to Musk. (Ignoring that Musk already owned 10 percent of Twitter so 4.4bn went straight into his own pocket, and other investors paid about 5bn).

Now the total effect would have been exactly the same. And everything is prepared by lawyers so that Musk owning Twitter, banks giving a loan to Twitter, Twitter handing the money to Musk and Musk handing the money to shareholders happen at the exact same moment.

Something similar happens when a normal person buys a house with a mortgage: The seller pays their mortgage back, the seller hands over the house, the new owner gets the mortgage from their bank and pays the seller, all exactly at the same time. It has to be done this way, or you could never buy a home with a mortgage.

Comment: I'm actually now confused about how taxes worked. In the "pays 13bn to Musk" scenario, wouldn't that attract tax of some kind?

Comment: I don't think the house mortgage analogy is correct. In the house mortgage the house is collateral and the owner owes the money, here Twitter is *not* the collateral - it's the debtor.

Comment: Littleadv: The analogy is that if you didn’t have lawyers setting it up so that things happen at the exact same time then you couldn’t buy a home. Sellers mortgage company doesn’t allow the sale without their mortgage repaid. Your mortgage company doesn’t give you the money if you don’t own the house.